# How to change the url parameter of every ajax function in the app on the go?

Tags: jquery

The question is simple. I have a lot of ajax functions all across my application.

Some examples are -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.dev.com/login/",
    data: data,
success: function(result)
        {   
            //success       
        },

            dataType: "json",
    });

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.dev.com/register/",
        data: data,
    success: function(result)
            {   
                //success       
            },

                dataType: "json",
        });
```

Now if I want to change my url from "`www.dev.com/login/`" to "`www.dev.com/login/?apikey=#########`", similarly for register, I will have to change the urls everywhere.

Instead I would like to be able to change the url of every ajax function on the go.

Like, have a script which detects when an ajax function is called and appends '`?apikey=######`' to the url parameter.

Thank you.

Comment: declare url variable globally and use it, or it is changing according on function call pass url as well, what is your requirement?

Comment: I want to be able to read the url and add GET parameters, before sending the ajax request.

Comment: You can use the $.ajaxSetup to set the extra parameter for each Ajax call. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `data-url` for DOM and make ajax request according to that `data-url`

**Example**

```
<a data-url="http://somelocation/login" >login</a>
<a data-url="http://somelocation/register" >Register</a>
```

Then you can get this data url into ajax url as below,

```
url: $(this).data('url'),
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$.ajaxSetup()` to set the required extra data with all the Ajax call made by the page through jQuery.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {apikey:"#####"}
});
```

Check the API over here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

You can check the console to see the parameters send to url. http://jsfiddle.net/MTHxt/1/

Answer (score 0):

As what I understand you require this

```
$(document).bind("beforeSend", function(){
   // this.url; do whatever you want to do with url 
 });
```

However I had not try with changing that url, you need to google for it.